# How can I have multiple websites all checkout on a common domain?

Tags: php, apache

I need to develop multiple e-commerce websites. Let's call them foobar1.com, foobar2.com and so on. The catch is, when you hit the final checkout button, the checkout process needs to happen at `checkout.foobar.com` for all domains.

Is this possible, and if so, how could it be done? Session data (that holds cart info) won't be available at the checkout.foobar.com, and neither will cookies.

One way I could get it to work is if I maintain the cart at foobar.com, which means everytime you add an item at foobar-n.com, I will make an API call to foobar.com which will update the cart.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You can always pass the session ID as a query parameter between the sites, and if the sites are on the same server or using the same session storage system, you can retrieve the carts that way... but passing session IDs in urls is usually a bad idea.

Comment: If you are putting them all together yourself, is it possible to get them co-hosted or co-located? If this is the case, you could get them all using the same db server and you wouldn't have to pass much more than an ID to get the contents of the cart ready for a transaction.

Comment: The sites will be on the same physical server. I did think of a database, but the issue is if someone reaches the checkout page and then changes their mind, I'll end up records in the db I no longer need. I suppose I could timestamp them and run a cron job to clear them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For the sake of not leaving this unanswered:*

I implemented the database solution, i.e. when you hit checkout, your cart contents are dumped into a database with a unique id, and you're then sent to checkout on `foobar.com?id={uniqid}` and cart contents are retrieved. When you successfully complete checkout, the items are removed from the DB. I also ran a nightly cron job that removed items from the DB that were more than 6 hours old (for those who didn't go through the checkout process).